# Adding firebase dependency causes gradle sync to fail

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I added the firebase database dependency via the Tools->Firebase->Add Real Time Database to your app method, and this causes my gradle sync to fail. I'm guessing either there is a conflict in dependencies (because I have already set up google sign in for my app using firebase and everything is working fine) or the wrong dependency was loaded

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Module Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nus.is3261.kotlinapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.shaishavgandhi:login-buttons:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Gradle File:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.70'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: show error logs

Comment: Change compile library from     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'   to "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'"

Comment: the error which pops up red is `Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0`

Comment: I'm curious, where did you find this `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'`? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo it was automatically added by android studio

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Replace

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

Comment: it worked with `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'`